# Kernel Panic - assert failed: [14083]:low wA f4 i1875522 s3180082 n16 d0 w1.6 tGC9 tL30

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, monterey, kernel-panic, kernel

For the past 2 weeks, I've experienced a few Kernel Panics. When looking at the crash logs, it specifies that there was an assert fail, containing the following information: `panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff00bb5c154): ANS2 Recoverable Panic - assert failed: [14083]:low wA f4 i1875522 s3180082 n16 d0 w1.6 tGC9 tL30, d:0x22401, a2:0x2890041, a3:0x60000000 - power(13)`. I noticed it usually happens when I am performing a lot of Memory and/or CPU intensive tasks, though I don't know if there is there is any true correlation between the two. Does anybody have an idea that the specific assert means? The following link is to a pastebin with the entire crash log: https://privatebin.randomserver.xyz/?fb94ef9e6656eb9f#Ah5qpzLErBk1ZqM4egsbnqGtTaPZnokx3dQoJHdoppbJ

Edit: I'm using an Intel MacBook Pro (2019), running macOS 12.5 (Monterey)

Comment: Which specific Mac model do you have?

Comment: @nohillside Intel Macbook Pro (2019)

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem with my Intel MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019). I'm running MacOS 12.2.1. My machine crashes about once per day with this error. It only started happening a few weeks ago - around the same time that OP posted this issue. @StrangeRanger - I wonder if you and I have something installed on our machines that's tickling a kernel bug? Do you have any of the following installed on your Mac? - XBox 360 Controllers plug-in
- Backblaze backup
- Google Drive Mac app
- iStat Menus
- Tailscale I figure if we have something in common we might isolate it to that piece of softw

Comment: Out of the one's you listed, I have iStat Menu installed. But I only recently reinstalled it. If I'm remembering correctly, these crashes were happening whether or not it was installed, but I can't be 100% sure, as I don't have the best memory.

Comment: I've also reinstalled macOS which seemed to have reduced the number of crashes. But to be fair, I haven't been running my Mac as intensively as I was when the crashes were heppening almost everyday. The crashes only started happing after I had updated to, I think macOS 12.4 or 12.5, so I've been wondering if it was a software bug.

Comment: I've installed some tools to continuously monitor the S.M.A.R.T. system and it keeps saying that it looks perfectly healthy. From the crash logs I've been keeping, my last Kernel Panic was on August 17th.

Comment: This is such annoying problem because it seems to only happen under very specific circumstances, like very intensive system tasks that are pushing the fans to go 100%. Anyways, sorry for this long response. Just thought I'd provide as much info as I could.

Comment: Have you had any success in troubleshooting/fixing this? I am in the same boat (2019 15" MBP) I wake up in the morning and see my Mac has shut down or rebooted - very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by disabling Spotlight from indexing my Bootcamp volume. I know this sounds odd, but it worked for me. In System Preferences, open the Spotlight pane, then select the Privacy tab. Press the + button and add Bootcamp to the list of volumes that Spotlight should not search.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/448523/470938

Comment: I'm on the same hardware as OP running OS 12.6. Just had my second crash of the day so i'll give this a shot and will report back next week!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no-one - except Apple developers with access to the source code - can tell you what that specific assertion means.

However, I can tell you that it is related to the storage subsystem on your MacBook Pro. It is likely to be a hardware error.

I would check and double-check that you have backups of the device - and then contact Apple support with this issue. Hopefully it is an issue that can be verified using hardware testing tools, so you can get the computer repaired.

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error two weeks ago. It started after I partitioned my storage drive to run an app on Windows 10. I believe it is related to the Mac firmware complaining about the size of a partition and resulting in a software issue related to memory block size, causing a ANS2 recoverable panic.

Do you have a partition? If so, I would check the size. I have read that it should be a number of bytes equal to a power of 2.

System Details

- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
- Monterey 12.6.1
- 500 GB SSD

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I currently run Bootcamp on my system, so yes it's partitioned, It's only using up around 300GB of space. I'm unsure what you mean by "I have read that it should be a number of bytes equal to a power of 2."

Comment: Apple recommends 256GB or larger hard drives for systems with a Boot Camp partition. Additionally, I have read that Windows 10 partitions on Macs should have at least 128GB. Your partition of 300 GB is higher than this so I’m surprised. The power of 2 detail comes from something related to the memory block size. I wish I could tell you more, I’m learning a bit on this too. For what it’s worth, I resized my partition to 128 GB and I don’t have these sudden shutdowns anymore.